# How do I change the default cell width of a notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I am so used to the Jupyter Notebook on the browser, that I feel VSCode's Jupyter Notebook cells are so wide. I was wondering if there is any way that I can reduce the width of the cell. **Simply, how to get additional padding on both sides.**

[My Current VSCode's Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcaVX.png)

[Jupyter Notebook in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxcYV.png)

Answer (score 1):

To make the cell width adjustable, View > Appearance > Centered layout.